# how can i copy css codes from website to my tumblr blog

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I found this website Noisli [dot] com

if you chick Background color it changes Automatically...
My question can I copy CSS style from this website to my Tumblr blog?

I would be grateful to anyone who helps me..
I need to copy a random Automatically colored background CSS code, I have already Googled it and I didn't found anything helpful.

can anyone help me with that issue?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.mydiv {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  color:black;
  font-weight:bold;
  animation: myanimation 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
  0% {background-color: red;}
  25%{background-color:yellow;}
  50%{background-color:green;}
  75%{background-color:brown;}
  100% {background-color: red;}
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">The background-color changes in time</div>
```

Source: https://codepen.io/herrberk/pen/GqrMvo

Comment: thank's alot. but i need to know were i well put second code <div class="mydiv">...</div> ؟؟

Comment: You have to add the class name in your HTML code.  for ex. add this CSS code on  your class OR add the class on your code where you want to add background animation

Comment: I am so bad with codes... I think it is easy with a click or tow.. thank's again bro